# How to avoid matrix/dataframe being piped (%>%) into list as an element in R

Tags: r, dplyr, pipe, magrittr

I want to create a list of matrices of correlations and covariances from a dataframe. I tried piping the dataframe into the list, using the magrittr pipe operator (`%>%`) as shown in the example below. The problem is that the dataframe itself gets inserted as the first list element. I am aware that the pipe operator default behavior is to inject the object into the first position in the function it gets piped into. However, I am curious to know whether there is an easy way to pipe the matrix/dataframe into functions in a list, while avoiding the insertion of the dataframe itself?

Code example:

```
library(magrittr) # alternatively 'dplyr'

matrix(1:27, ncol = 6) %>% as.data.frame() %>%
list(
    a = list(
        cor(.[,1:3]),
        cov(.[,1:3])
    ),
    b = list(
        cor(.[,4:6]),
        cov(.[,4:6])
    )
)
```

Output:

```
[[1]]                          # I want to avoid inserting the 
A data.frame: 4 × 4            # dataframe as an element
V1  V2  V3  V4
<int>   <int>   <int>   <int>
1   5   9   13
2   6   10  14
3   7   11  15
4   8   12  16

$a
   A matrix: 2 × 2 of type dbl
   V1   V2
   V1   1   1
   V2   1   1

   A matrix: 2 × 2 of type dbl
   V1   V2
   V1   1.666667    1.666667
   V2   1.666667    1.666667

$b
   A matrix: 2 × 2 of type dbl
   V3   V4
   V3   1   1
   V4   1   1

   A matrix: 2 × 2 of type dbl
   V3   V4
   V3   1.666667    1.666667
   V4   1.666667    1.666667
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, after I posted, I realised I hadn't really considered to check if there are other operators that might work. According to [`magrittr`'s introduction page](https://magrittr.tidyverse.org/articles/magrittr.html), *"the “exposition” pipe, `%$%` exposes the names within the left-hand side object to the right-hand side expression."* It seems it wasn't necessarily intended for this purpose, but I replaced `%>%` with `%$%`, and now it works! (I am still unaware of potentioal drawback to using `%$%`, so any comments on this is appreciated.)

```
library(magrittr)

matrix(1:16, ncol = 4) %>% as.data.frame() %$%
list(
    a = list(
        cor(.[,1:2]),
        cov(.[,1:2])
    ),
    b = list(
        cor(.[,3:4]),
        cov(.[,3:4])
    )
)

# $a
#     A matrix: 2 × 2 of type dbl
#     V1    V2
#     V1    1   1
#     V2    1   1

#     A matrix: 2 × 2 of type dbl
#     V1    V2
#     V1    1.666667    1.666667
#     V2    1.666667    1.666667

# $b
#     A matrix: 2 × 2 of type dbl
#     V3    V4
#     V3    1   1
#     V4    1   1

#     A matrix: 2 × 2 of type dbl
#     V3    V4
#     V3    1.666667    1.666667
#     V4    1.666667    1.666667
```

Comment: This is quite exciting! storing that one for future use!

Comment: This is a nice solution, but the problem with this operator is that few R users now specifically use `magrittr`, and the `%$%` operator is not available in the `tidverse`.

Answer (score 3):

Just add `extract` to you pipeline to get the result without the first element:

```r
library(magrittr)

matrix(1:30, ncol = 6) %>% as.data.frame() %>%
list(
    a = list(
        cor(.[,1:3]),
        cov(.[,1:3])
    ),
    b = list(
        cor(.[,4:6]),
        cov(.[,4:6])
    )
) %>%
  extract(-1)
#> $a
#> $a[[1]]
#>    V1 V2 V3
#> V1  1  1  1
#> V2  1  1  1
#> V3  1  1  1
#> 
#> $a[[2]]
#>     V1  V2  V3
#> V1 2.5 2.5 2.5
#> V2 2.5 2.5 2.5
#> V3 2.5 2.5 2.5
#> 
#> 
#> $b
#> $b[[1]]
#>    V4 V5 V6
#> V4  1  1  1
#> V5  1  1  1
#> V6  1  1  1
#> 
#> $b[[2]]
#>     V4  V5  V6
#> V4 2.5 2.5 2.5
#> V5 2.5 2.5 2.5
#> V6 2.5 2.5 2.5
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

---

**Addendum**

An alternative to `extract` is `[`:

```r
matrix(1:30, ncol = 6) %>% as.data.frame() %>%
list(
    a = list(
        cor(.[,1:3]),
        cov(.[,1:3])
    ),
    b = list(
        cor(.[,4:6]),
        cov(.[,4:6])
    )
) %>%
  `[`(-1)
```

Comment: `extract` is definitely handy! According to R's help pages, it has the alias `[`. However I am unable to get the syntax using the alias to work. Any suggestions? I also found a [very simple solution using `%$%`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72057986/9434803).

Comment: @PålBjartan I have added an addendum to show how the syntax works with the `[` operator

Comment: Thanks! I interpreted the aliases to be used similar to operator in syntax, and not as a function, which led to leaving backticks and parentheses out.

Answer (score 2):

You could pipe it into an anonymous function to tell R explicitly where to use your dataframe in constructing the output list:

```r
library(tidyverse)

matrix(1:30, ncol = 6)  %>%  as.data.frame()  %>%
  (function(df) {
    list(a = list(cor(df[, 1:3]),
                  cov(df[, 1:3])),
         b = list(cor(df[, 4:6]),
                  cov(df[, 4:6])))
  })
#> $a
#> $a[[1]]
#>    V1 V2 V3
#> V1  1  1  1
#> V2  1  1  1
#> V3  1  1  1
#> 
#> $a[[2]]
#>     V1  V2  V3
#> V1 2.5 2.5 2.5
#> V2 2.5 2.5 2.5
#> V3 2.5 2.5 2.5
#> 
#> 
#> $b
#> $b[[1]]
#>    V4 V5 V6
#> V4  1  1  1
#> V5  1  1  1
#> V6  1  1  1
#> 
#> $b[[2]]
#>     V4  V5  V6
#> V4 2.5 2.5 2.5
#> V5 2.5 2.5 2.5
#> V6 2.5 2.5 2.5
```

It's perhaps one of the limitations of the `magrittr` pipe that (as far as I'm aware) it seems to be not possible to tell it not to pass LHS in as first argument - unless presumably it's explicitly used in same level of function elsewhere (as in `lm` examples)? As shocking to the system as the migration to the new pipe (`|>`) is, maybe its added elements will overcome this issue in the future.

<sup>Created on 2022-04-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: I did find a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72057986/9434803) using the `magrittr` exposition pipe, which apparently can be used for this issue.